# execve : convert execve call to fork

Tags: c++, unix

I have an execve system call to overlay my curernt program with another one. The code works fine but I my requirement is to change this execve system call with fork system call. I am trying something like below:

```
pid_t child_pid;
child_pid = fork();
if(child_pid == 0) {
       if (-1 == execve(...)) //Normal previous execve call
       {
          .............
       }
}
else
{ //fork parent process
exit(0);
}
```

I am not sure that when we are replacing an execve system call by fork what things we should take care. In my child process I am calling the existing execve call to let the original flow be maintained (as if without fork) but what should the parent do - should I normally exit or I need to wait for the child process to exit/die. The execve call overlays the current process with a new one so there is no question of parent / child process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the **exit status** of the child needs to be known, or if there is some operation to be performed **after** the child process exits, call [`wait()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) in the parent.

If there is no need for either of the above, you can exit the parent process. The [orphaned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process) process will be re-parented by `init`, and hence will have no adverse effects.

Answer (score 0):

That's up to you. If you don't need to wait around, then you can just exit in which case the child process will become orphaned.

Answer (score 0):

```
 should I normally exit or I need to wait for the child process to exit/die
```

It depends on you, and your requirements, if needed you can wait for child process using wait(...), have a look at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fwait.htm

Also have a look at http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork